# Can JSON support a list of objects that can be queried by SQL?

Tags: json, postgresql

I'm trying to construct a JSON object and I want to query out specific results, specifically, I'm going to use Postgres reading JSON data.

**Example JSON:**

```json
{
  "ports": [
    {"p1":{"interactions_type":{"num_rds":4,"num_wrts":8},"interactions_dynamics":{"rds_min":1,"rds_max":10}}},
    {"p2":{"interactions_type":{"num_rds":7,"num_wrts":2},"interactions_dynamics":{"rds_min":6,"rds_max":8}}},
    {"p3":{"interactions_type":{"num_rds":14,"num_wrts":6},"interactions_dynamics":{"rds_min":5,"rds_max":50}}}
  ]
}
```

Some of the queries I want to run:

1. Select all the port names (p1,p2,p3)
2. Select the number of ports (3)
3. Select all the `interactions_dynamics` in for for port p2 ("rds_min":6,"rds_max":8)
4. Select the ports with `interactions_type` -> `num_rds` >= 7 (p2,p3)
5. Select the port name, `interactions_type` -> `num_wrts`, `interactions_dynamics` -> `rds_min`
   where `ineraction_dynamics` -> `rds_max` > 20 ("p3,6,5")

You get the idea, SQL-like flexibility. The JSON structure I have is probably wrong to support what I need to do, either that or I don't know how to write the queries.

Can anyone suggest a better way to structure this?

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using?

Comment: Change that `{"p1":{…}}` structure into `{"id": "p1", …}` or you'll have a real hard time. Alternatively use `{"ports": { "p1":{…}, "p2":{…}, "p3":{…} } }` instead of an array, if you really must, but notice that you'll loose ordering (just like in a SQL relation).

Comment: Have you read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html?

Comment: Why do you want to use JSON? All of this would be so much simpler with a normal SQL table.

Comment: "SQL-like flexibility" - then don't use JSON.

Comment: PG version = 11.5                                                                  
I tried  {"ports": { "p1":{…}, "p2":{…}, "p3":{…} } } but don't know how to query the port names given that construct (I don't know the names in advance).
I could put this in regular SQL tables, but the customer promises it will be very dynamic.... "alter table" all the time to support the new data and older data may not "fit" into the new model.

Comment: Normalize your data model, then this gets really easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to which version you use in the database, you can use [Postgres document json](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) for extract data from JSON.

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=06bfbbe7c2fa2f542d3c7ff2270e765f)

```sql
-- select all the port names (p1,p2,p3)
---------------------------------------

select
  jsonb_object_keys(jp) as "port names"
from 
  test t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.data -> 'ports') jp;
  
-- select the number of ports (3)
---------------------------------
  
select
  jsonb_array_length(t.data -> 'ports') as "number of ports"
from 
  test t;
  
-- select all the interactions_dynamics infor for port p2 ("rds_min":6,"rds_max":8)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

select
  jp -> 'p2' -> 'interactions_dynamics'
from 
  test t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.data -> 'ports') jp
where
  jp ? 'p2';
  
-- select the ports with interactions_type -> num_rds >= 7 (p2,p3)
------------------------------------------------------------------

select
  jpv.key
from 
  test t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.data -> 'ports') jp
  cross join jsonb_each(jp) jpv
where
  (jpv.value -> 'interactions_type' ->> 'num_rds') :: int >= 7;
  
-- select the port name, interactions_type -> num_wrts, interactions_dynamics -> rds_min where ineraction_dynamics -> rds_max > 20 ("p3,6,5")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

select
  jpv.key,
  (jpv.value -> 'interactions_type' ->> 'num_wrts') :: int,
  (jpv.value -> 'interactions_dynamics' ->> 'rds_min') :: int
from 
  test t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.data -> 'ports') jp
  cross join jsonb_each(jp) jpv
where
  (jpv.value -> 'interactions_dynamics' ->> 'rds_max') :: int >= 20;
```